# Why can't I decode a too heavy bpg image in my browser?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, bpg

Using the bpg encoder provided by Fabrice Bellard [here](http://bellard.org/bpg/libbpg-0.9.7.tar.gz), the following instructions on my Debian 8 [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181735/how-to-install-bpg-better-portable-graphics-on-linux-mint-17/259639#259639), I've done some compressions tests and displayed the results on my browsers (firefox chrome) with the .js provided (or you can use [this website](https://webencoder.libbpg.org/show.html)).

When I want to display a bpg image whose weight is above than (approximately) 800 KB (original wheight: 2.6 MB and size 3600x2700), I have the following error message in the console:

```
> Successfully compiled asm.js code (loaded from cache in 21ms) 

> pre-main prep time: 0 ms

> Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 33554432, (2) compile with ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, or (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY before the program runs.
> uncaught exception: abort() at wa@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:19:34
> B@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:85:320
> z.b@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:11:48
> Z@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:53:333
> Vd@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> fd@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> sd@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> Mc@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> Sc@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> Tc@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> _b@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:66:1 Kb@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:66:1
> Pc@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> Pd@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> Kd@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:70:1
> @https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js line 15 > eval:1:84
> window.BPGDecoder.prototype.load/d.onload@https://webencoder.libbpg.org/js/bpgdec8.js:88:216 If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.

> Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 33554432, (2) compile with ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, or (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY before the program runs.
```

Does anyone know where does this error come from?

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong and what you can do about it: "Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 33554432, (2) compile with ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, or (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY before the program runs."

Comment: Well ... it's odd for me that only the image's weight is responsible for this bug

Answer (score 1):

The section 7 in the README file gives the origin of the problem:

> The 8 bit only decoders are a little faster and consumes less memory
>   (16 MB instead of 32 MB by default, you can change the memory
>   configuration in the Makefile if you want to handle larger images).

=> By default too larges images are encoded in a way that can't be displayed by the JavaScript file!

How to fix that problem is explained in the error code (see above): you have to edit the appropriate lines in the Makefile then recompile the project.